# Brew can't find or install older mongodb versions

Tags: mongodb, homebrew

I need to use an older version of mongodb community edition v.3.6. I've installed it before via brew but now it seems like the command: `brew install mongodb-community@3.6` can't find the older version. Anyone have any fixes for this, or do I just need to manually install mongodb with the `.tgz` file.

```
$ brew install mongodb-community@3.6
Warning: No available formula with the name "mongodb-community@3.6". Did you mean mongodb-community, mongodb-community@5.0, mongodb-community@4.2 or mongodb-community@4.4?
==> Searching for similarly named formulae and casks...
==> Formulae
mongodb/brew/mongodb-community                           mongodb/brew/mongodb-community@4.2
mongodb/brew/mongodb-community@5.0                       mongodb/brew/mongodb-community@4.4

To install mongodb/brew/mongodb-community, run:
  brew install mongodb/brew/mongodb-community

==> Casks
mongodb-compass

To install mongodb-compass, run:
  brew install --cask mongodb-compass
```